# TideSDK app on Mac

Tags: linux, windows, macos, tidesdk

I developed an app via TideSDK on OSX. I have a .app and It is working on OSX. However, you know it cannot work on linux or windows. I want to run my app on linux or windows. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, you package for each platform. As you are aware mac apps do not run on Windows and it is the same with TideSDK since you are creating something native for each platform.
TideSDK must be installed on each platform to create an executable and bundle for it.

To generate an installer for each system, you need to run commands on each system (windows / linux 32bit / linux 64bit) using tidebuilder.py on the command line.

We will have more to speak about concerning packaging quite soon that will make the task of building and distributing your apps easier. Stay tuned for updates !!